# Single phase induction stove push in quick connector difficult to connect

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, stove, connectors

We had to change the current stove we had for and induction one (long story) which I also installed. With this new one, I have a 5 wire single phase setup. I think it is because each stove module where each side must have it own connection, L and N. Since they are connected that way, I can't fit them through the quick push in connectors the electrician left.

I have several ideas, but I want to get input.

1. Should I just cut the sleeving further back? (example in image) and should I take off the terminal because it also a bit thick to fit through the quick connector?
2. Just remove the sleeving and leeve the terminal?
3. Remove sleeving and terminal and add a new terminal? I never did that but should be straightforward.
4. Remove everything and replace the 3-way connection quick connect to a 4-way?

Notes:

- Breakers and everything were prepared for this type of connection.
- Our home connection is monophase, therefore, I'm showing the stove diagram for monphase connection.

Diagram of what I'm trying to explain and the brand connection diagram.

[image: Diagram]

[image: Complementary live pic]

[image: Current main and oven setup]

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for the comment. The 4bay connector was what i was thinking was the safest, but i didnt know if i should do it for a single phase connection. Regarding the wiring, the supposed professional jammed the 2 earth connections from the main and the oven in the same bay... im not a licensed eletrician so Im trusting that... D: I should buy a 3bay one for the earth connections shouldn't I?? P.S.I didnt install the oven

Comment: I'm not a licensed electrician, and that's why I removed my comment, this is just what I would probably do to solve the problem, but I'll let someone else more knowledgeable to give better advice.  My original comment was to not put 2 wires into a single bay of the connectors.

Comment: @Matthew off course Im also just seeing everyones opinion before I consider going to a store and also ask them. Everyone as their own opinion (even store guys). Hence me making the question. I normally don't have any problem in "basic" domestic wiring but i never had this situation. D: But this seems a relativevly simple solution i just never encountered it..

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? The two wires are clamped together with some kind of crimp sleeves?

Comment: That is what I am wondering as well. If so they probably are treated as one wire, and the only issue here is that whoever did the install was too lazy to get an additional 3-way connector for the earth.

Comment: @Martin, Oven has the earth (flexible) wire cramped into the quick connector with the not flexible one from main. Regarding the stove wiring yes, neutral and phase wires are clamped with a terminal as to my understading to be used as 1 wire in a monophase setup, which is the case here in PT domestic use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A picture of your actual connectors would help, but my guess, based on how you drew them, is that those are Wago lever-lock type connectors and, to my knowledge, those are *NOT* rated for more than one wire per lever.

Pick up some 5-position Wagos (check yours for the model number and get the 5-postion of the same model to ensure they're designed for the wire size you've got, those if this is how your electrician did it, you may want to confirm you've got the correct ones to begin with), and put one wire in each position.

Do **NOT** cut back insulation to make it easier to cram an extra wire in. You do **NOT** want any bare wire showing between the wire's own insulation and the plastic protective portion of the connector. That's where shorts happen, at best causing the breaker to trip and dinner to be delayed, at worst starting a fire.

---

Based on the update with pictures of the actual installation, I fully stand behind my original answer.

It appears that the electrician had run out of 5-hole Wagos (or had to go all the way back to the truck to get some), but had ferrules in his pocket, so he crimped two wires in one ferrule and left it that way for the OP to install.

Noting that not all the wires have ferrules, I would cut the ferrule off the black/brown pair, strip the insulation back, and individually insert each into its own port in a 5-port Wago. *NOTE: Check your local laws/electrical code to ensure that it's approved to do this. You may be required to crimp a ferrule on each wire before inserting it into the Wago. If that's the case, that's another error the electrician made.*

Once that's done, you can reuse the 3-port Wago that was on the brown wires to connect the 3 separate ground wires instead of trying to cram the 3rd wire into the 2-port Wago.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan, seems about right. Yes... I think they are wagos... I may update in an hour or so with a "Live" photo. Im currently in between houses and with everything i forgot to take a picture. But as my talk with previous users I was confirming the 3 bay connector wasnt the ideal for this use case.

Comment: @JoãoSantos Note the update to this answer.

Comment: Good tip, @jay613, I've included that in the answer, thanks!

Comment: Gotcha! I'd then seems i was thinking sort of right. Many thanks really FreeMan. Ill go to my hardware store get the wagos i need and ask them about the ferrules use, cus from my understanding i never saw them in any instalation (on other houses). But again not a certified eletrician here and only did what i'd call "basic" connections. Just a tangent the wiring load i think is done correctly cus theres a breaker only for stove/oven but ill check the amps to be sure. Tomorrow ill mark it as the answer after i come from the shop. Again thnks for the patience!

Comment: I doubt that it was the electrician to crimp those ferrules. Chances are they are original from the factory, so that the end user won't connect the wrong combination

Comment: @Martin, yup, they came factory assembled. The shtty connections of the stove and what they told me to do thats on them tho xD hence me needing not biased opinions. Everything working fine now, I couldnt removed them so i shorten them just by the crimps lenght made them right size for the wagos (tangent: the main's cables had copper out of the wagos i only find out once i changed the wagos D: ) I fixed that too now everything is properly connected and works fine. Thank you all once again for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Your stove is able to accept 3-phase wiring. To distribute the current over two supply lines they specified the shown connection.

What works in my jurisdiction, but not necessarily in yours:

You can now either find an connector that accepts the shown sleeve (cembre z6/3 comes to mind or perhaps wago 221-613) or cut the wires as indicated, remove the insulation and get an 5 post connector.

Since your picture already indicates wago-lever type connectors: The Wago 221-415 should be fine with 5 posts. Please check that the maximum current of the breaker is lower than the specified max. current of the connector (depends on jurisdiction)

And yes, the earth connector should be corrected as @KMJ said.

Comment: Right. Seems consistent with what everyone is saying tomorrow I’ll go down do the electric store because i only have 3 bay ones. I updated the question to have “live” photos but i dont think its gonna change what all of you are saying. Thanks a lot.